# Maximum pressure at a compressor outlet and molecular weight

Tags: thermodynamics

I am puzzled by some data I see for a compressor. From what I read, the maximum discharge pressure reachable with a reciprocal compressor would vary depending on the nature of the gas used, and its molecular mass (maximum pressure lower with a heavier gas). This does not seem to fit with my quickly jotted notes from a perfect gas point of view, in which molecular mass shouldn't matter. Any explanation ?

Comment: Do you mean "reciprocal" compressor, or "centrifugal" compressor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

centrifugal compressors actually achieve a higher pressure ratio with heavier gases - because their working depends on storing energy in the form of the kinetic energy of the gas, and it's easier if the gas has a higher molar mass.

The relationship may go in the opposite direction for reciprocating compressors because the kinetic energy of the gases isn't helpful here. Instead, the gases have to be lifted and heavier gases probably consume more energy at some stage, or something like that.

At any rate, I think that the "simple" physics model you're thinking about - with pressure's being independent of the type of the (nearly ideal) gas - is correct and the reason for the dependence on the gas will be of an engineering character, rather than a fundamental physical character: it's probably due to a subtlety dependent on some detailed steps that make the device work.

All the best, LM